# Javascript create SVG path bottom up vs top down

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a page that shows a grid of job positions and I am showing the progression from one to another by using SVG + paths to draw the connection between boxes.

My code is working just fine when I am connecting an element at the top to one at the bottom. It is finding the XY of the top box and the XY of the bottom box and connects the two.

My issue is I want to flip this code and go from the bottom up. This means I need the top XY of the bottom element and the bottom XY of the top element and draw the path.

I have been trying to flip offsets around and basically do the opposite of what is working but I think my math is wrong somewhere.

Here is what the top down approach looks like. Works just fine.
[image]

The bottom up approach however is not correct. Theres some math errors somewhere and the calculations are causing the SVG to be cut off.
[image]

I believe the answer lies within the `connectElements()` function as that is where the coordinates are determined.

Any thoughts on how I can get these calculations corrected?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ly59a2hf/2/

**JS Code:**

```
function getOffset(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
    top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
    width: rect.width || el.offsetWidth,
    height: rect.height || el.offsetHeight
  };
}

function drawPath(svg, path, startX, startY, endX, endY) {

  // get the path's stroke width (if one wanted to be  really precize, one could use half the stroke size)
  var style = getComputedStyle(path)
  var stroke = parseFloat(style.strokeWidth);

  // check if the svg is big enough to draw the path, if not, set heigh/width
  if (svg.getAttribute("height") < endY) svg.setAttribute("height", endY);
  if (svg.getAttribute("width") < (startX + stroke)) svg.setAttribute("width", (startX + stroke));
  if (svg.getAttribute("width") < (endX + stroke * 3)) svg.setAttribute("width", (endX + stroke * 3));

  var deltaX = (endX - startX) * 0.15;
  var deltaY = (endY - startY) * 0.15;
  // for further calculations which ever is the shortest distance
  var delta = deltaY < absolute(deltaX) ? deltaY : absolute(deltaX);

  // set sweep-flag (counter/clock-wise)
  // if start element is closer to the left edge,
  // draw the first arc counter-clockwise, and the second one clock-wise
  var arc1 = 0;
  var arc2 = 1;
  if (startX > endX) {
    arc1 = 1;
    arc2 = 0;
  }
  // draw tha pipe-like path
  // 1. move a bit down, 2. arch,  3. move a bit to the right, 4.arch, 5. move down to the end 
  path.setAttribute("d", "M" + startX + " " + startY +
    " V" + (startY + delta) +
    " A" + delta + " " + delta + " 0 0 " + arc1 + " " + (startX + delta * signum(deltaX)) + " " + (startY + 2 * delta) +
    " H" + (endX - delta * signum(deltaX)) +
    " A" + delta + " " + delta + " 0 0 " + arc2 + " " + endX + " " + (startY + 3 * delta) +
    " V" + (endY - 30));
}

function connectElements(svg, path, startElem, endElem, type, direction) {

  // Define our container
  var svgContainer = document.getElementById('svgContainer'),
    svgTop = getOffset(svgContainer).top,
    svgLeft = getOffset(svgContainer).left,
    startX,
    startY,
    endX,
    endY,
    startCoord = startElem,
    endCoord = endElem;

  console.log(svg, path, startElem, endElem, type, direction)

  /** 
   * bottomUp - This means we need the top XY of the starting box and the bottom XY of the destination box
   * topDown - This means we need the bottom XY of the starting box and the top XY of the destination box
   */
  switch (direction) {

    case 'bottomUp': // Not Working

      // Calculate path's start (x,y)  coords
      // We want the x coordinate to visually result in the element's mid point
      startX = getOffset(startCoord).left + 0.5 * getOffset(startElem).width - svgLeft; // x = left offset + 0.5*width - svg's left offset
      startY = getOffset(startCoord).top + getOffset(startElem).height - svgTop; // y = top offset + height - svg's top offset

      // Calculate path's end (x,y) coords
      endX = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().left + 0.5 * endElem.offsetWidth - svgLeft;
      endY = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().top - svgTop;

      break;

    case 'topDown': // Working

      // If first element is lower than the second, swap!
      if (startElem.offsetTop > endElem.offsetTop) {
        var temp = startElem;
        startElem = endElem;
        endElem = temp;
      }

      // Calculate path's start (x,y)  coords
      // We want the x coordinate to visually result in the element's mid point
      startX = getOffset(startCoord).left + 0.5 * getOffset(startElem).width - svgLeft; // x = left offset + 0.5*width - svg's left offset
      startY = getOffset(startCoord).top + getOffset(startElem).height - svgTop; // y = top offset + height - svg's top offset

      // Calculate path's end (x,y) coords
      endX = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().left + 0.5 * endElem.offsetWidth - svgLeft;
      endY = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().top - svgTop;

      break;
  }

  // Call function for drawing the path
  drawPath(svg, path, startX, startY, endX, endY, type);



}

function connectAll(direction) {

  var svg = document.getElementById('svg1'),
    path = document.getElementById('path1');

  // This is just to help with example. 
  if (direction == 'topDown') {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('box_1'),
      div2 = document.getElementById('box_20');
  } else {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('box_20'),
      div2 = document.getElementById('box_1');
  }

  // connect all the paths you want!
  connectElements(svg, path, div1, div2, 'line', direction);


}

//connectAll('topDown'); // Works fine. Path goes from the bottom of box_1 to the top of box_20
connectAll('bottomUp'); // Doesn't work. I expect path to go from top of box_20 to the bottom of box_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you can simplify things by making the SVG the exact right size.  Ie. fit it between the two elements vertically, and have it start at the leftmost X coord.

If you do that, the path starts and ends at either:

- X: 0 or svgWidth
- Y: 0 or svgHeight.

Then as far as drawing the path goes, it's just a matter of using the relative directions (startX -> endX and startY -> endY) in your calculations.  I've called these variables `xSign` and `ySign`.  If you are consistent with those, everything works out correctly.

The last remaining complication is working out which direction the arcs for the rounded corners have to go - clockwise or anticlockwise.  You just have to work out the first one, and the other one is the opposite.

```
function getOffset(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
    top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
    width: rect.width || el.offsetWidth,
    height: rect.height || el.offsetHeight
  };
}


function drawPath(svg, path, start, end) {

  // get the path's stroke width (if one wanted to be  really precise, one could use half the stroke size)
  var style = getComputedStyle(path)
  var stroke = parseFloat(style.strokeWidth);
  var arrowHeadLength = stroke * 3;

  var deltaX = (end.x - start.x) * 0.15;
  var deltaY = (end.y - start.y) * 0.15;
  // for further calculations which ever is the shortest distance
  var delta = Math.min(Math.abs(deltaX), Math.abs(deltaY));
  var xSign = Math.sign(deltaX);
  var ySign = Math.sign(deltaY);

  // set sweep-flag (counter/clock-wise)
  // If xSign and ySign are opposite, then the first turn is clockwise
  var arc1 = (xSign !== ySign) ? 1 : 0;
  var arc2 = 1 - arc1;

  // draw tha pipe-like path
  // 1. move a bit vertically, 2. arc,  3. move a bit to the horizontally, 4.arc, 5. move vertically to the end 
  path.setAttribute("d", ["M", start.x, start.y,
                          "V", start.y + delta * ySign,
                          "A", delta, delta, 0, 0, arc1, start.x + delta * xSign, start.y + 2 * delta * ySign,
                          "H", end.x - delta * xSign,
                          "A", delta, delta, 0, 0, arc2, end.x, start.y + 3 * delta * ySign,
                          "V", end.y - arrowHeadLength * ySign].join(" "));
}


function connectElements(svg, path, startElem, endElem, type, direction) {

  // Define our container
  var svgContainer = document.getElementById('svgContainer');

  // Calculate SVG size and position
  // SVG is sized to fit between the elements vertically, start at the left edge of the leftmost
  // element and end at the right edge of the rightmost element
  var startRect = getOffset(startElem),
      endRect = getOffset(endElem),
      pathStartX = startRect.left + startRect.width / 2,
      pathEndX = endRect.left + endRect.width / 2,
      startElemBottom = startRect.top + startRect.height,
      svgTop = Math.min(startElemBottom, endRect.top + endRect.height),
      svgBottom = Math.max(startRect.top, endRect.top),
      svgLeft = Math.min(pathStartX, pathEndX),
      svgHeight = svgBottom - svgTop;

  // Position the SVG
  svg.style.left = svgLeft + 'px';
  svg.style.top = svgTop + 'px';
  svg.style.width = Math.abs(pathEndX - pathStartX) + 'px';
  svg.style.height = svgHeight + 'px';

  // Call function for drawing the path
  var pathStart = {x: pathStartX - svgLeft, y: (svgTop === startElemBottom) ? 0 : svgHeight};
  var pathEnd   = {x: pathEndX - svgLeft,   y: (svgTop === startElemBottom) ? svgHeight : 0};
  drawPath(svg, path, pathStart, pathEnd);

}

function connectAll(direction) {

  var svg = document.getElementById('svg1'),
      path = document.getElementById('path1');

  // This is just to help with example. 
  if (direction == 'topDown') {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('box_1'),
      div2 = document.getElementById('box_20');
  } else {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('box_20'),
      div2 = document.getElementById('box_1');
  }

  // connect all the paths you want!
  connectElements(svg, path, div1, div2, 'line');

}

//connectAll('topDown');
connectAll('bottomUp');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93Le85tk/3/

Comment: That is awesome! Looks like it solves my question, I will just need to look into the situation of a straight line. When I try to go first bottom left box to top left box, no line appears at all. I will need to determine how to check for that and then not include the arcs I am guessing - http://jsfiddle.net/jLgmucbn/